# Find which Logic Pro project files contain specific plugin?

Tags: mac, audio, search, plugins, logic

Do you think it might be possible to search a folder of Logic Pro session files and figure out which of them uses a certain plugin?

I'm preparing to upgrade to the latest Mac OS, and before I do, I'll need to find all the projects that use legacy plugins that will no longer be compatible and render the audio in place. I think a lot of people, whether they've thought of this or not, would find this helpful, as OS upgrades often make older projects unplayable for this reason.